# Get property from model in array

Tags: model, sapui5

Im trying to get Property from JsonModel

this is my code:

`acountsJson = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("acounts").getProperty("/acounts/");
    alert(acountsJson.length);
    acoutnJson[0].getProperty("/uName");`

in first alert I get the lenght but I can't get property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `getProperty` is a javascript-object, so you can get inner elements by using a `.`

In your case `acountsJson[0].uName`

I recommend you to use `console.log` instead of `alert`, you can get more detailed output.

Answer (score 0):

acoutnJson[0].getProperty("/uName");

acount is misspelled maybe that's why?